# Relative speed of jagged, multidimensional arrays and object fields

Tags: c#, object, multidimensional-array, field

Some background, im an engineer not a professional programmer so apologies for any dumb questions. I have a program that is calculation intensive and i want to speed it up. My understanding (from reading forums) was that C# is optimised for Jagged Arrays, but my test below seems to say not. If i'm doing something wrong please let me know, also the test which uses the tray object (could be any moderately complex object) seems too fast, is there a problem with the code?

The relative speeds im getting (in debug) are; (Note: I just realised the times include array initislisation, but thats ok, the arrays will be cleared or re-initialised many times in the program).

Object/field access 0ms
Jagged Array access 87ms
Normal Array access 12ms

If i dont count initialising the arrays i get 0, 7 and 7 ms respectively.

```
var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
double res=0;
int count = 10000;
Tray tray = column[0][4];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    tray = column[0][4];
    tray.T = i;
    res = tray.T;
}
watch.Stop();

var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Debug.WriteLine("Column Solution Time1 ms: " + elapsedMs.ToString() + " " + res.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("Object Field" + elapsedMs.ToString());


watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
double res2 = 0;
int count2 = count;
double[][] tray1 = new double[count2][];
for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
    tray1 = new double[count2];

for (int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
{
    tray1[i][i] = i;
    res2 = tray1[i][i];
}
watch.Stop();

elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Debug.WriteLine("Column Solution Time2 ms: " + elapsedMs.ToString() +" "+ res2.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("Jagged Matix" + elapsedMs.ToString());

watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
double res3 = 0;
int count3 = count;
double[,] tray3 = new double[count3,count3];

for (int i = 0; i < count3; i++)
{
    tray3[i,i] = i;
    res3 = tray3[i,i];
}
watch.Stop();

elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
Debug.WriteLine("Column Solution Time3 ms: " + elapsedMs.ToString() + " " + res3.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("Matix" + elapsedMs.ToString());
```

Comment: Bad bench-mark, it does not measure the array access cost.  At issue is that the array is not initialized, a demand-paged virtual operating system allocates storage and reserves space in the paging file when the array is accessed the first time.  Since it is not initialized, that is what you actually measure.   A relatively expensive operation, the difference is that the jagged array does that 10,000 times but the multi-dim array does it once.  Just initialize the arrays before you start the stopwatch, you should now see 0 msec for all tests.

Comment: I tried it that way as mentioned above
"if i dont count initialising the arrays i get 0, 7 and 7 ms respectively."